# Map marker info window without small triangle at bottom

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to show an Infowindow of a Google map marker without the small triangle at the bottom. Please check the image which I have attached.

[image]

I tried by setting by changing setInfoWindowAnchor but it didn't work. Can anyone help me on this?

```
marker_info.setInfoWindowAnchor(0,0)
```

Comment: why you down voted for this question ?

Comment: Try to use custom marker infowindow check out : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to use the speechbubble, use the `getInfoContents()` override.

In order to not use the speechbubble, use `getInfoWindow()` override.

Example 1:

```
public class MyCustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final View myContentsView;

    MyCustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
        myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.info_window, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        TextView tvTitle = ((TextView) myContentsView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtTitle));
        TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentsView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtSnippet));

        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
        tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

        return myContentsView;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: using speechbubble]

Example 2:

```
public class MyCustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final View myContentsView;

    MyCustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
        myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.info_window, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        TextView tvTitle = ((TextView) myContentsView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtTitle));
        TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentsView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtSnippet));

        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
        tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

        return myContentsView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

       return null;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: No Speechbubble]

Note, here is the info_window.xml layout file used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:textColor="#D3649F"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSnippet"
        android:textColor="#D3649F"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how to add space below info window when not using the speechbubble?