# unwanted white frame surrounds my customized GoogleMaps Info Window

Tags: android, android-layout, google-maps-api-3

I use a customized info window so that I can achieve a gray background and white text color. Yet, I get a white frame around it. I want all of the Info Window to be gray, that is including its triangular edge that points to the spot.

I use this code in my `Activity`:

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
    @Override  // Use default InfoWindow frame
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) { return null; }
    @Override // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_info_window, null);
        TextView tv_location = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
        tv_location.setText(marker.getTitle());
        return v;
    }});
```

and this is my layout:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_info_window"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31018084/map-marker-info-window-without-small-triangle-at-bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the `getInfoWindow ()` method and inflate you custom layout in that function.

From [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.html#getInfoWindow(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker))

> `public abstract View getInfoWindow (Marker marker)`
>
> Provides a custom info window for a marker. If this method returns a
>   view, it is used for the entire info window. If you change this view
>   after this method is called, those changes will not necessarily be
>   reflected in the rendered info window. If this method returns null ,
>   the default info window frame will be used, with contents provided by
>   `getInfoContents(Marker)`.

```
 @Override  // Use default InfoWindow frame
    public View getInfoWindow (Marker marker){
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_info_window, null);
        TextView tv_location = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
        tv_location.setText(marker.getTitle());
        return v;
    }
    @Override // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
    public View getInfoContents (Marker marker){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

So i think you should reverse your function implementation.